# Font Awesome light macro type error unit test

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

Not able to select the font awesome 6 icon in the jest unit test. Throws the error given below.
Any idea how to mock the light function from the module ?

```
TypeError: (0 , import_macro_1.light) is not a function

     31 |                     <Tooltip title="Execute Basket Order Pre-Trade" placement="top" disableInteractive>
     32 |                         <span>
   > 33 |                             <FontAwesomeIcon color="#26b7cd" className="cursor-pointer basket-grid-execute" fontSize="20px" fontWeight="300" icon={light('play')} />
        |                                                                                                                                                         ^
     34 |                         </span>
     35 |                     </Tooltip>
     36 |                     <Tooltip title="Edit Basket Row" placement="top" disableInteractive>
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry. Cannot produce a different example to the one already provided as it should capture the jist of the issue.